# Default GNU screen "screens"

Tags: gnu-screen

As the title says, I would like to set up GNU screen on my headless box such that when it starts up with some screens already running.

My `.bashrc` file runs screen on the first login with `screen -xRR` and I would like `htop` and various logs to be automatically opened.

Is it also possible to assign titles to the screens at the same time?

Comment: There are similar useful questions on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/386059/how-can-i-start-multiple-screen-sessions-automatically) and [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/147715/screenrc-multiple-regions-on-launch/147748). Also I believe that the [Screen documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) uses the term “window” for what you are calling a “screen”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define default windows in your Screen configuration file, `~/.screenrc`.

Window titles can be set inline with the `-t` option, but working directories must be set in advance of launching each window. For example, in your case you might include the following:

**~/.screenrc**

```
# ...

chdir ~
screen -t "Htop" htop

chdir /var/log
screen -t "System log" tail -F syslog
screen -t "Mail log" tail -F mail.log

chdir ~
screen   # Extra Bash window for running commands

# ...
```

Note that the `screen` here is not the `screen` command you run, but an internal `screen` command. See [`man screen`, section on Customization](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/screen.1.html), or [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Screen-Command) for more.

Answer (score 3):

You could take advantage of the `-S` flag, and provide a unique name you'd like to give the screen.

```
screen -S MyTitleHere
```

You can also load configuration files, using the `-c` flag.

```
screen -S foo -c /home/user/.screenrc.bar
```

You could try something such as:

```
su -c "screen -dm -S $TITLE 2>&1 1>/dev/null" $USER
```

And place it in your `/etc/rc.local`, which would cause that screen to be created when you boot up for a specific user.

Once you get your configuration (`.rc`) files set up, you'll probably want to run something along the lines of:

```
screen -dURS $TITLE -c /path/to/.screenrc.bar
```

As this will

1. Create the screen session if it doesn't exist
2. Re-Attach to the session if it already exists.

---

Another option would be to use `tmux` and `tmuxinator`, which provide a cleaner experience, in my opinion.  You can set up `tmux` to use the screen-style keybindings, if you're used to that.  I say this because I've had much better success running `tmux` for other users than I have had with screen.