# Attaching tmux to an existing session, or creating a new session

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

For a while, I used `screen -dURS` to [solve this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645647/default-gnu-screen-screens).

The goal is to be able to run a command that attaches to an existing session with a specific name, or creating a session with a specific name and running a command in that new session.  A specific example would be to load a server or daemon if it's not running, or to simply attach to the session if it is running.

I have been reading `man tmux` and the closest I have gotten to this goal is the following:

```
tmux new-session -AD -t TMUXSessionName 'echo Banana'
```

> The -A flag makes new-session behave like attach-session if session-name already exists; in the case, -D behaves like -d to attach-session.
>
> If -t is given, the new session is grouped with target-session.  This means they share the same set of windows - all windows from
>   target-session are linked to the new session and any subsequent new windows or windows being closed are applied to both sessions.
>   The current and previous window and any session options remain independent and either session may be killed without affecting the
>   other.  Giving -n or shell-command are invalid if -t is used.

Am I misunderstanding these flags?  Am I trying to do something that's not supported by `tmux` natively?

Note:  I find `tmux` easier to explain to less technically savy people and because of the way it allows sessions to be shared easily, I'd like to be able to switch to `tmux` from `screen` and this issue is the only thing I haven't been able to figure out to allow me to do the switch completely.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to make the following change:

```
tmux new-session -AD -s TMUXSessionName 'echo Banana'
```

So that we are using `-s` and **not** `-t`.