# How can I rejoin my existing tmux session - but if I don't have a session running, create a new one

Tags: tmux

I use tmux quite a bit, especially on remote servers that I connect to via SSH. I can start a new tmux session by simply running `tmux`, and I can re-connect to an existing session with `tmux a`. But, if I run `tmux a`, and I don't have a session running, it just says this:

```sh
$ tmux a
no sessions
```

That makes sense, as I don't have one running. Is there a way to detect if a session is running, and if there is one already running, connect to it, but if there *isn't* one running, start a new one?

Unlike [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739901/attaching-tmux-to-an-existing-session-or-creating-a-new-session), I don't care about session names as I don't use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different and shorter solution: Run `tmux ls` - if the output is empty create a new session - if not attach.

```sh
$ if [[ -z $(tmux ls) ]]; then tmux; else tmux a; fi
```

Also, maybe this is a bit more logical and easy to understand, since you don't have to consider error redirection and exit codes.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to attempt to re-connect to an existing session, and if that fails (presumably due to there being no sessions), start a new session:

```sh
$ tmux a > /dev/null 2>&1; if [[ "$?" == "1" ]]; then tmux; fi
```

(the `> /dev/null 2>&1` hides the `no sessions` message, `"$?"` is the exit code, which we check to determine if we need to start a new one)

This appears to work, although it is rather long. Maybe there is a better/shorter way?