# How do I start screen with multiple splits directly from the command line?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I'm using `screen` after I have logged in with `ssh` to my server. As of now I set up the splits in my screen window by hand and run the commands by hand as shown in the following screen-shot:

[image]

- The top part should run `tail -n 1 -f /home/server/log/access.log`.
- The lower right part should run `htop`
- The lower left one should simply be a command prompt

Is there any way to have that be done via commands/script, so I not have to redo it every time by hand?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/645647/default-gnu-screen-screens?

Comment: @muru This quite answers it for the part how to start the separate screens, just not the part how to have them directly ordered like above shown.

Comment: Everything that can be done using shortcuts in screen can be done using commands in `.screenrc`. For this arrangement we have [the `split` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Regions).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the specific case of window arrangements, there's a screen command to save them to a file: `layout dump`. From [`man screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/screen.1.html):

```
layout dump [filename]

Write to a file the order of splits made in the current layout. This is
useful to recreate the order of  your  regions  used  in  your  current
layout.  Only  the  current  layout is recorded. While the order of the
regions are recorded, the sizes of  those  regions  and  which  windows
correspond  to  which regions are not. If no filename is specified, the
default is layout-dump, saved in the directory that the screen  process
was  started in. If the file already exists, layout dump will append to
that file. As an example:

           C-a : layout dump /home/user/.screenrc

will save or append the layout to the user's .screenrc file.
```

So, once you make the arrangement manually, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>, then type `layout dump /path/to/some/file`. The layout will be saved to `/path/to/some/file` and you can then restore it in  a new session with:

```
screen -c /path/to/some/file
```

Comment: +1 nice one; The `split -v` seems undocumented :) this is why I was struggling.

Comment: @Videonauth it actually is documented under default keybindings section.  `C-a |       (split -v)    Split the current region  vertically  into two new ones.`

Comment: Yes, it looks it's only mentioned in the manpage, next to `C-a |`, but not in the GNU docs

Comment: Found an odd behavior you might want to mention: If you type for example `layout dump ~/layout` the process will fail, it need to full path (i.e. `/home/$USER/layout`)

Comment: @Videonauth since tilde expansion is usually done by the shell, it's not surprising if a given command doesn't support it internally. Some do, most don't.

Comment: I can't dump the layout from a detached session by following: `screen -r SESSION_NAME -X layout dump FILE_NAME`. Other commands work fine with `-X`.

Answer (score 15):

I came up with the following to create the output shown in my question and following [@muru's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/980920/522934). Using `layout dump` gave me the following:

```bsh
split
focus
split -v
focus
```

> Note: Tilde (`~`) expansion does not work with `layout dump` so instead of `~/layout.dmp` for example you would need to use `/home/<username>/layout.dmp`.

From which I then created the following `.screenrc`

```bsh
# create the top screen
chdir /home/server/log
screen -t "Apache Log" tail -n 1 -f access.log
# split the screen and focus onto the new created space
split
focus
#create the bash
chdir /home/server/log
screen
# split vertically and focus onto the new area
split -v
focus
# create the htop screen
screen -t "Htop" htop
# focus twice to end up with the bash area active
focus
focus
```

Now I only need to type `screen` and get my wanted layout started. I leave that here as an example for those who are wondering, but don't forget to up-vote @muru's answer, since he is the one who made me able to solve this.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to come up with a setup I wanted. I put it in a more specifically named file (e.g. example.screenrc) and am launching screen using `screen -c example.screenrc`. Like you mentioned, `~` doesn't work in the rc file, however `$HOME` does. Another thing I noted is that the screen command only supports simple (literal) arguments. Naturally, it's not a shell with all the fancy expansions etc. If these are needed, can just use, as an example, `screen -t "http-server" bash -c 'http-server --hostname $(hostname -s)'`.