# screen: I start two screens, but there is only one?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, screen, virtual-console

After doing

```
screen -S foo
screen -S bar
screen -ls
```

I see two screens: `1234.foo` and `5678.bar` (both Attached).

How can they be both attached, as I'm only in one at a time? (Presumably the last one I started?) Perhaps I misunderstand the concept, what does 'Attached' or 'Detached' mean?

Now, when I press: <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> to get a list of screens, I only see ONE entry: `0 bash`.

Perhaps I misunderstand this concept as well, shouldn't there be *two* screens?

When I do `screen -ls` it still shows two screens, both still Attached. How do I know which one I'm currently in?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/980910/how-do-i-start-screen-with-multiple-splits-directly-from-the-command-line ?

Comment: @Videonauth Thanks, but what does 'attached' or 'detached from your current screen session' mean, exactly? I would assume I'm working on one screen at a time, so I'm attached to that one, and the rest is detached. But in my example above, they are *both* attached even though I am in only one of them at a time? (I'm not using split screen layout or anything)

Comment: @Videonauth Also, would you know why `Cltr+A` `"` shows only one entry (`0 bash`) even though I have two sessions? And can I see in which one I am currently working? For example if I named them "foo" and "bar", can I see if I'm currently in the foo or bar session?

Comment: @Videonauth Sorry maybe I'm just missing a trivial point here, put exactly what does "attached to you" or "associated with you" mean in this context? If I start a screen session, start some process there, detach from it, and then kill my ssh, the process keeps running (I understand this is the purpose of screen). However if I don't detach, if I'm actively in the screen session (or reattached to it) and then kill my ssh, the process *still* keeps running: if I reconnect and do `screen -list` they are both there, including the one I was just attached to when killing my the ssh connection.

Comment: By the way, `screen -list` shows both sessions: `1234.foo` and `5678.bar`, both Attached. I can't seem to find a way to tell in which I am currently (or perhaps in neither).

Comment: `$ echo $STY` will show you the PID and session name (if you started with `screen -S`. It will be empty if you're not attached.