# How to remote access Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: remote-access

I have tried a number of ways to connect to my Ubuntu 17.10 desktop using my laptop also running on 17.10. But at all times I happen to end up with a bluish screen and then lastly a pop up notification (Just can't get to my desktop). Any solutions please..?

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: "wayland" is the output

Comment: The following link may add some details about the problem and a possible solution, https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w; but it is a good idea to switch from Wayland to Xorg, as suggested in the answer by @Videonauth

Answer (score 1):

The most, if not all current remote desktop tools wont work with Wayland, to mitigate this I'd suggest switching back to Xorg. You can do that by simply logging out and when logging back in clicking that small cogwheel icon and choose 'Ubuntu on Xorg' (see screen-shot).

[image]

To make Wayland completely unavailable you can even go further and disable it system wide by editing `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and change the following line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

into:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

This will disable the usage of Wayland on your system even for the login screen. After that X11 is being used again and the most common screen-sharing/remote access programs should work again.

Comment: It still fails.  Am using Remmina

Comment: Sadly I have no knowledge according to Remmina, afaik there are some more problems according 17.10 but don't nail me down on it. The main culprit is still Wayland, for me it made OBS studio, and teamviewer not working.

Comment: Thanks but what do you always use to remotely access the machine.

Comment: When accessing my laptop I use teamviewer and other way around same, and for my server i use simple ssh, I'm anyways more a terminal jockey.

Comment: Team viewer works like fine but it requires that its running on the server machine and given that i must know the password displayed on the server makes it even more disturbing. If only i could get one where only the I.p address of the server machine is required and then sign in details.

Comment: OpenVNC if you not need sound for example?

Comment: Its just like am always running some program installed on the server through the terminal. Key and most important is to run the program and save the output into a separate file. Thats ideally all

Comment: The you could simply use SSH, thats what I'm always doing and for logging, do the log on the server and get it from time to time via sftp. Here is an example how i see my server through ssh in a terminal https://askubuntu.com/q/980910.

Comment: What are the implications of changing the default "Wayland" for the prior "Xorg"? (I don't really know what either of those do beyond 'display stuff'.)